# How to draw a shape on a Google Map and get the area for that shape

Tags: ios, maps

I want to implement a functionality in which any one can draw any shape on the Google Maps via fingers. Then I want to show the markers or pins on the map which only lies in that area/Shape.
I know that there are various ways to draw a shape on google Map but how can i know that any particular pin lies inside that area drawn by the user/person. Is there any Google API available for it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing the shape as `UIBezierPath`. Loop through your list of locations and translate long and lat to CGPoint so you can call

```
BOOL showLocation = [bezierPath containsPoint:point];
```